# using avr atmega32 as web server using ENC28J60 chip

Tags: avr, atmega, ethernet, website, enc28j60

looking for help on making a website on ATMega32 using the ENC28J60 chip
iam searching for more than a week .. i found many already-made projects on this, but nothing worked with me .. iam very confused through various projects where everyone is using a different method.
also the mikroc example for this ethernet module (after configuring it a little in the HTML code) didn't work with me ..

- first, i want to know how to simulate the ethernet module RJ45 on Proteus, so that i can try the code on simulation before the real-time.
- if anyone is familiar with this avr-ethernet based website i'd appreciate his help.
  i think my problem is in the code (firmware), as i bought an ENC28J60 board where i just connect the SPI pins directly to my MCU and it's VCC & GND.

Answer (score 4):

avr-uip http://code.google.com/p/avr-uip/ is a port of the free UIP network stack to the AVR, it has a driver for the ENC28J60 and a web server example.

To simulate the system on a PC, I'd recommend trapping ethernet frames at the point of entry/exit from UIP.

Comment: can you explain more about the simulation .. 
iam trying to use the provided driver in the link you gave, iam alittle confused which compiler can i use .. iam familiar with the avr studio 5 & IAR .. but it makes errors using it .. which compiler should i use in your opinion

Comment: For questions about the project, you should contact the authors through the google code page. I believe it requires GCC.

Comment: iam now able to say that my hardware is connected very good .. as i used an already made .hex file for ATMega32 and i was able to access the website built on it through my PC using a cross-over ethernet cable ..

the code i used is made by mikroelektronika (mikroc) .. but when i try to make my own main.c file using the given library of mikroelektronika .. i makes problems in compiling .. and the generated code doesn't work .. 
iam sorry iam late in my response .. but i wasn't free the last couple of days

Comment: and the code in the website you gave .. when i compile it using avrstudio it makes errors .. that iam not able to fix ... (avr studio has a GCC)

Comment: You should contact the author of the code